# SVG gradient file renders to Graphics incorrectly

Tags: c#, svg, bitmap, render, gradient

We are dynamically generating an image file for the specified size. There are 3 layers:

- base image layer (Load jpeg, resize it to the required size, use as Bitmap)
- gradient image layer (load SVG, resize it, render  on base image layer)
- text layer (render on base image layer + SVG gradient)

The issue is with the SVG layer, it is rendered differently comparing to the original:
[image: rendered vs original]

SVG layer render code is following

```
private void RenderGradientLayer(Graphics mainGraphics, ImageDrawSettings settings)
{
    var gradientSvg = SvgDocument.Open(settings.FullGradientFilePath); //d:\path-to-file.svg
    var gradientBitmap = gradientSvg.Draw(settings.TargetSize, settings.TargetSize); //500x500
    mainGraphics.DrawImage(gradientBitmap, 0, 0);
}
```

Setup of Graphics

```
private static void Init(Graphics graphics)
{
    graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
    graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
    graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
    graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;
}
```

SVG content

```
<svg width="144" height="144" viewBox="0 0 144 144" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<rect width="144" height="144" fill="url(#paint0_linear)"/>
<defs>
<linearGradient id="paint0_linear" x1="72" y1="144" x2="72" y2="2.40787e-07" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop stop-opacity="0.8"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#C4C4C4" stop-opacity="0"/>
</linearGradient>
</defs>
</svg>
```

Are there any ideas why SVG can be rendered incorrectly?

UPDATE:
Found the reason and posted it lower.

Comment: An SVG file is XML format and is text.  the issue could be in the SVG file or the graphic mode (graphic card) of the machine (default settings and images supported).

Comment: What does your function `gradientSvg.Draw()` do? is that from some external library? In addition, please show the source text of the SVG file.

Comment: @ccprog Draw() is method of SvgDocument(Assembly Svg, Version=3.1.0.0)

SVG content was added

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found the reason and it is graphics setup:

```
graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
```

Removing that line makes the gradient to be rendered correctly